Plot Size error : attempt to use zero-length variable name
I try to adapt the size of a plot. It was working well on a previous version of R. After a recent update I have the error
attempt to use the zero-length variable name

with an alert on this line of code. Can you help me ?
Thank you

fit8 <- survfit(Surv(SG,Statut) ~ MMR, data = colon)
names(fit8$strata) <- gsub("MMR=", "", names(fit8$strata)) # permet d'enlever la partie variable= devant les modalité de la variable dans la légende 
graph8 <- ggsurvplot(fit8, data = colon,           xlab = "Time in months", break.time.by = 12, xlim = c(0,84), pval=TRUE,           risk.table = TRUE, risk.table.height = 0.38,           legend.title="",  # on enlève le mot "Stata" devant la légende, on peut metttre ce qu'on veut comme titre           surv.median.line = "hv",            title = "Overall survival", font.main = c(13, "black"),           palette = c("#441199","#EE6677","#8FD175","#CCBB44","#66CCEE"),           legend = "right")

I try to increase the height of the graph but it didn't work

You should add also a snippet of your code that includes the plot function.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

fit8 <- survfit(Surv(SG,Statut) ~ MMR, data = colon)
names(fit8$strata) <- gsub("MMR=", "", names(fit8$strata)) # permet d'enlever la partie variable= devant les modalité de la variable dans la légende 
graph8 <- ggsurvplot(fit8, data = colon,
           xlab = "Time in months", break.time.by = 12, xlim = c(0,84), pval=TRUE,
           risk.table = TRUE, risk.table.height = 0.38,

risk.table = TRUE, risk.table.height = 0.38,
legend.title="",  # on enlève le mot "Stata" devant la légende, on peut metttre ce qu'on veut comme titre
surv.median.line = "hv",
title = "Overall survival", font.main = c(13, "black"),
palette = c("#441199","#EE6677","#8FD175","#CCBB44","#66CCEE"),
legend = "right")
